# boost tokenizer / char separator

Tags: c++, boost, tokenize

I have tried with both commented and uncomented version of the code:

```
string separator1(""); //dont let quoted arguments escape themselves
string separator2(",\n"); //split on comma and newline
string separator3("\"\'"); //let it have quoted arguments

escaped_list_separator<char> els(separator1, separator2, separator4);
tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char>> tok(str);//, els);


for (tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char>>::iterator beg = tok.begin();beg!= tok.end(); ++beg) {
next = *beg;
boost::trim(next);
cout << counter << " " << next << endl;
counter++;
}
```

to separate a file which has the following format:

```
 12345, Test Test, Test
 98765, Test2 test2, Test2
```

This is the output

```
0 12345
1 Test Test
2 Test
98765
3 Test2 test2
4 Test2
```

I am not sure where the problem is but what I need to achieve is to have a number 3 before 98765

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the newline separator: `string separator2(",\n");`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;

   using namespace boost;

int main() {
    string str = "TEst,hola\nhola";
    string separator1(""); //dont let quoted arguments escape themselves
    string separator2(",\n"); //split on comma and newline
    string separator3("\""); //let it have quoted arguments

    escaped_list_separator<char> els(separator1, separator2, separator3);
    tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char>> tok(str, els);

    int counter = 0, current_siding = 0, wagon_pos = 0, cur_vector_pos = 0;

    string next;

    for (tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char>>::iterator beg = tok.begin();     beg != tok.end(); ++beg) {
        next = *beg;
        boost::trim(next);
        cout << counter << " " << next << endl;
        counter++;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is true, but with now I have an error :candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided

Comment: Yes I did the same, but didn't you receive that error engine.cpp:43:84: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::escaped_list_separator<char>::escaped_list_separator(std::string&, std::string&, std::string&, std::string&)’     candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided

Comment: Sorry, my bad, in separator2 you can use a string contaning some field separators

Comment: I've just tested the last change in your code and it is compiling fine. Unfortunately the output hasn't changed - I still need a solution

Comment: What we haven't noticed is that we left ;//, els); commented, but when I uncomment it I am having this error    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me you are *parsing*, not splitting.

Using a parser generator would be superior IMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a091d6d252abef3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(std::cin >> std::noskipws), l;

    std::vector<std::string> columns;
    qi::parse(f, l, +~qi::char_(",\r\n") % (qi::eol | ','), columns);

    size_t n = 0;
    for(auto& tok : columns) { std::cout << n++ << "\t" << tok << "\n"; }
}
```

Prints

```
0   12345
1    Test Test
2    Test
3   98765
4    Test2 test2
5    Test2
```

Frankly I think it's superior because it will allow you write

```
phrase_parse(f, l, (qi::_int >> *(',' >> +~qi::char_("\r\n,")) % qi::eol, qi::blank...);
```

And get proper parsing of the data types, whitespace skipping etc. for "free"